# Express $\operatorname{sech}^{-1}(x)$ in terms of logarithms

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to express the following  $\operatorname{sech}^{-1}(x)$ in terms of logarithms, and would warmly appreciate feedback towards my approach. The solution should be :

$$\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{(1-x^2)}}{x}\right)$$ when $x > 0.$ However, I cannot seem to get this. My working out:

$y = \operatorname{sech}^{-1}(x)\implies \operatorname{sech}(y) = x$

$$-\operatorname{sech}(y)\operatorname{tan}(y) = x; $$

Once I got to here, I decided to transform the $\operatorname{sech}$ and $\tan$ into their hyperbolic identities.

$$-\dfrac{\operatorname{sinh}(y)}{\operatorname{cosh}^2(y)}=\dfrac{e^y-e^{-y}}{2}(\dfrac{e^y+e^{-y}}{2})^2 = x$$

Though I've tried reworking this into a quadratic form $\dfrac{b \space \pm \space \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$, however, I couldn't manage to get the right form. I would greatly appreciate some help on the next steps towards this.

Comment: Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question.

Comment: Why not go first to $sech(y)=1/(\cosh(y))$ and then use definition of $\cosh(y)$ in terms of exponentials.

Comment: I don't see how you got $\tan$ here. Perhaps you meant $\operatorname{tanh}.$ In that case $-\operatorname{sech}(y)\operatorname{tanh}(y)=-x\sqrt{1-x^2}\neq x.$

Comment: Reading through the answers, I realised that I was very close to this before the try above whilst practising on scrap-paper, but I made a simple arithmetic mistake that led me elsewhere. I must be getting tired!

Answer (score 3):

Once you have $\operatorname{sech}(y) = x$ it implies $$\dfrac{e^y+e^{-y}}2=\dfrac1x$$ which simplifies to the quadratic $$xe^{2y}-2e^y+x=0$$ of $e^y.$ Now solve for $y$ as you discribed in the last sentence.

Answer (score 2):

By definition $\operatorname{sech}(x)$ is equal to
$$y = \frac{2}{e^x+e^{-x}}.$$
What we now want to do is solve for $x$. First, divide both sides by $2$ and then take the multiplicative inverse of both sides to get $$\frac{2}{y}=e^x+e^{-x}$$
Now substitute $u=e^x.$ We will get a new and easy equation.
$$u+\frac{1}{u}=\frac{2}{y}.$$ You should be able to solve this equation for $u$
$$u=\pm\sqrt{y^{-2}-1}+\frac{1}{y}.$$
If you are done, don't forget to substitute back $e^x=u$.

Answer (score 1):

Forming a quadratic as outlined in the above answers is a fine approach, and one I recommend above this one. Here's a different one, which relies on knowing beforehand that
$$\cosh^{-1}x=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$$
Let $y=\operatorname{sech} ^{-1} x$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{sech}y=x&\iff \cosh y=\frac{1}{x}\\
&\iff y=\operatorname{sech}^{-1}x=\cosh^{-1}\frac{1}{x}=\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}\right)
\end{align}$$
Simplifying yields the correct answer. I hope that was helpful. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Note

\begin{align}
\text{sech}\left(\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}x \right)
=& \frac2{ \exp\left(\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}x \right)+\exp\left(-\ln \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\right)}\\
 = &\frac2{ \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}x + \frac x{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}}
=\frac2{ \frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}x + \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}x }
=x
\end{align}

Thus

$$\text{sech}^{-1}x =\ln\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}x $$

Comment: This only shows that $\ln\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{(1-x^2)}}{x}\right)$ is a right inverse to $\operatorname{sech}(x).$ We also need to prove the other identity or bijectivity of one of these functions.